# Data validation across the same ranges through several sheets but the list is different

Tags: excel, vba, loops

I have several sheets that all have the same template. Each sheet has a range of data validation in which the "list" is unique for each sheet.

```
'LUNDI (JOUR)
With Sheets("LUNDI (JOUR)").Range("A8:H78").Validation 'The range here is always this
    .Delete
    .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= _
    xlBetween, Formula1:="='Index NE PAS SUPPRIMER'!$C$2:$C$11" 'This is what changes, it increments by 3 with every sheet.
    .IgnoreBlank = True
    .InCellDropdown = True
    .InputTitle = ""
    .ErrorTitle = ""
    .InputMessage = ""
    .ErrorMessage = ""
    .ShowInput = False
    .ShowError = False
End With

'MARDI (JOUR)
With Sheets("MARDI (JOUR)").Range("A8:H78").Validation
    .Delete
    .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= _
    xlBetween, Formula1:="='Index NE PAS SUPPRIMER'!$F$2:$F$11"
    .IgnoreBlank = True
    .InCellDropdown = True
    .InputTitle = ""
    .ErrorTitle = ""
    .InputMessage = ""
    .ErrorMessage = ""
    .ShowInput = False
    .ShowError = False
End With
```

Instead of copying and pasting this code for every sheet, is there a way to loop through all the sheets and only change the `Formula1:=` part?

[image: Replica of what it looks like. Highlighted area is the area that has the data validation. This area is the same across all sheets.]

[image: On this sheet we can find the lists which are different depending on the sheet. The lists have 2 columns between them and it continues until column AP.]

Comment: What logic to be applied in order to change the range in `Formula1`? I mean, would you want to pass `$C$2:$C$11`, `$F$2:$F$11"`, or is it some logic to be applied in order to build it?

Comment: On the cell above of `$C$2:$C$11` there is the name of the sheet written, so there is `LUNDI (JOUR)` written, on the cell above `$F$2:$F$11` there is `MARDI (JOUR)` written so maybe search for the sheet name and select 10 cells below. Or, maybe increment `$C$2:$C$11` by 3 so that it returns `$F$2:$F$11`, then the next one would be `$I$2:$I$11`, etc. I'm not sure.

Comment: So, incrementing the range column with 3 will be OK? If it isn't it somehow related to the sheet name and it can be built in this way, I will prepare an answer... Can you edit your question and put, at least, a picture with two such sheets to be processed. And relation between the above range definition and something else...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code, please:

```
Sub testSolveValidation()
  Dim sh As Worksheet, wb As Workbook, strFormula As String, rngForm As Range
   Set wb = ActiveWorkbook 'use there the workbook you need
   Set rngForm = Range("$C$2:$C$11")
   For Each sh In wb.Worksheets
        solveValidation sh, rngForm.address
        Set rngForm = rngForm.Offset(, 3)
   Next
End Sub

Sub solveValidation(sh As Worksheet, strFormula As String)
 With sh.Range("A8:H78").Validation 'The range here is always this
    .Delete
    .aDD Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= _
    xlBetween, Formula1:="='Index NE PAS SUPPRIMER'!" & strFormula 'This is what changes, it increments by 3 with every sheet.
    .IgnoreBlank = True
    .InCellDropdown = True
    .InputTitle = ""
    .ErrorTitle = ""
    .InputMessage = ""
    .errorMessage = ""
    .ShowInput = False
    .ShowError = False
End With
```